# where does org-mode get the \author field for latex output

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

My exported pdf and and .tex file both include a name inherited from the logged-in unix account, I am having trouble over-riding this setting with #+LATEX_HEADER: \author {}  in the .org file.

Watch for **Tom Smith** vs. **Joe Brown** in this code.
The question is, where does org-mode derive the **Tom Smith** from?
my .bib file includes the lines at the top, I don't see any setting to explain this.

```
% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
% Created for Tom Smith at YYYY day t
% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8)
```

my .org file says

```
#+LATEX_HEADER:\author{Joe Brown}
```

When I look in the exported .tex it has 2 lines

```
\author{Joe Brown}
\author{Tom Smith}
```

the compiled pdf features **Tom Smith**
Where does org-mode get the \author field from if it's not declared in

```
#+LATEX_HEADER:\author{} ?
```

Is it coming from ~/.emacs.d/.init.d ?
Neither **Tom Smith** nor **author** are anywhere in my .spacemacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each export back-end has `AUTHOR` keyword, associated with global variable `user-full-name`.  If it's empty, the `\author` will not be exported.  You could redefine it into the file (buffer) with

```
#+AUTHOR: Joe Brown
```

This will set only one `\author`, which is defined into the buffer even if the `user-full-name` is not empty.

Org didn't check that you define author with `LATEX_HEADER: \author`, it just outputs these lines.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if I don't put Joe Brown in the .org there is \author{Tom Smith} in the .tex (that it's pulling from the os) If I do put Joe Brown in the .org the .tex has \author{Joe Brown} first and \author{Tom Smith} on the next line. The outputted .pdf shows the 2nd value (from the os) whether than the attempted override from the .org.

Comment: If you interested why LaTeX use second author, that's because it redefine first occurrence.  You need to remove your `LATEX_HEADER: \author...` and put into the org file only `AUTHOR: ...`

Answer (score -2):

Emacs **documentation**:

```
M-x describe variable user-full-name
```

user-full-name is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is "Tom Smith"  ::
The full name of the user logged in.

You can **customize** this variable.
**solution**: Click on **customize** and change to Joe Brown inside emacs.

**further explanation**: the full name of the logged in user is not the same as your short-account-name.  It can be obtained from a shell prompt by:

```
finger `whoami` | awk -F: '{ print $3 }' | head -n1 | sed 's/^ //'
```

If you desire the pdfs you write in org mode to have a different name than your unix user full name, you can override the value inherited from the os.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in a meaningful way

Comment: Which is really funny, because I just noticed that you're also the one who asked the question